# Help on intuition for posets and continuity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, continuity, monotone-functions

I'm currently going through Theories of Programming Languages (ToPL) and am struggling a bit with building up an intuition for posets in certain instances. While I can somewhat follow the math, I feel like I don't fully "get it", so hoping someone can help here.

---

#### Example

So, to take an example in something concrete, in ToPL page 32. We first get given that a function, $f$, is continuous if and only if, for all chains $x_0 \sqsubseteq x_1 \sqsubseteq x_2 ...$ in P,

$f(\bigsqcup\limits_{i = 0}^\infty x_i) = \bigsqcup\limits_{i = 0}^\infty{}' fx_i$

**Now, suppose** *P* is the vertical domain of the natural numbers, and *P'* is the two-element domain $\{ \bot', \top' \}$. Then the monotone function $fx=\text{if } x = \infty \text{ then } \top' \text{ else } \bot'$,

[image]

is not continuous, since the limit of $\{0,1,...\}$ is $\infty $ and $f \infty $ is $\top'$, but the limit of $\{f0, f1,...\} = \{\bot'\}$ is $\bot'$.

---

#### Question

Where I kinda get lost is, from the original given equation, I can certainly follow the LHS, where it goes $\bigsqcup\limits_{i = 0}^\infty x_i = \infty$ and then $f(\infty) = \top'$, but the RHS I don't know how they get $\{f0, f1,...\} = \{\bot'\}$. I would assume that in $x_i$ you could find $\infty$ and then you would end up with $\top'$, which means the constraints hold. Where does that $= \{\bot'\}$ come from?

Hope this made sense, think it got a bit messy :/

Comment: I agree with you. **If** the function $f$ is defined on the "special" number $\infty$, then $\bigsqcup\limits_{i = 0}^\infty{} fx_i= \{ f(0), f(1), \ldots \} = \{ \bot, \top \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon my abuse of notation here, I'm not sure what is used in the book. The chain $x = (x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (0, 1, 2, \ldots)$ does not include $\infty$, so the set $\{f(x_i) \mid i \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}\}$ is just $\{\bot'\}$. Hence we find that

$$ \bigsqcup_{i=0}^\infty f(x_i) = \bigsqcup \{f(x_i) \mid i \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}\} = \bigsqcup \{\bot'\} = \bot'$$

However, we have that no positive integer $n$ bounds the chain $x$ from above, the least element that does is $\infty$. So $\bigsqcup_{i = 0}^\infty x_i = \infty$. Then

$$ f\left(\bigsqcup_{i = 0}^\infty x_i\right) = f(\infty) = \top'$$

Comment: Correct... but in the book it is not written that way. The function $f$ is defined for $\infty$; thus, if $\infty$ is in the domain of $f$, $f(\infty)$ must be in the image. I think that the presentation is a bad example of calculus: $\infty$ is not a number and the author move from the symbol $\bigsqcup^{\infty}$ to the conclusion that $\infty \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The poset on the left is, as a set, $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$, and $f$ is defined by $f(n) = \bot'$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $f(\infty) = \top'$. Since the chain $(0, 1, 2, \ldots)$ does not include $\infty$, the image of this chain under $f$ is the same as $f(\mathbb{N}) = \{\bot'\}$.

Comment: So would it be fair to generalize that in our chains we will never have limit itself, so that is why we do not get $\{\bot', \top'\}$ but instead end up with $\{\bot'\}$? Which in turn implies that any function which only defines the limit of $P'$ as the mapping of the limit of $P$ would then never be continuous? (am I going too far here?).

Comment: @Tehnix No, chains can still contain the limit. For example, the chain $(1, 2, 3, \infty, \infty, \infty, \infty, \ldots)$ contains its limit, which is $\infty$.

Comment: @Joppy Then I'm not quite sure I understand the reasoning behind {f0,f1,...} not also including $f\infty$? :/